# Cannot verify openssl smime verify over SSH

Tags: ssh, openssl, certificate, verification, smime

I'm trying to SSH into the server at my university in order to do an OpenSSL assignment. I have my self-signed certificate `aasignedcert.pem`, the private key it was signed with `aaprivatekey.pem` and my plaintext `test.txt`.

I first signed my message to create my `testsigned.txt` file with the command:

`openssl smime -sign -signer aasignedcert.pem -in test.txt -inkey aaprivatekey.pem > testsigned.txt`

Then, encrypted the file to make `testsigned.txt.enc`:

`openssl smime -encrypt -in testsigned.txt -aes128 aasignedcert.pem > test.txt.enc`

To make sure everything works, I decrypted that file and stored it in `testsigned.dec.txt`:

`openssl smime -decrypt -aes128 -in test.txt.enc -inkey aaprivatekey.pem > test.dec.txt`

The decrypted file indeed has the original plaintext. Finally, I attempted to verify it using my certificate that I signed it with:

`openssl smime -verify -in test.dec.txt -CAfile aasignedcert.pem -certfile aasignedcert.pem`

This, however, does not work. Even with fiddling with the parameters, I consistently get this error message:

`Verification failure
139814549997256:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:342:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate`

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create aasignedcert.pem?  Perhaps you self-signed it using a local CA that you created?  If this is the case, I believe you need to pass *the certificate of the CA* to the -CAfile argument.

openssl smime -verify -in test.dec.txt -CAfile [certifcate of the CA] -certfile aasignedcert.pem

Comment: Yep, totally missed that one. I knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the checking of the key certificate when verifying a message you can supply the -noverify parameter to the verify command (though openssl smime verify -noverify does look a bit weird).